# Android: Disable triple zoom for one application

Tags: android, accessibility

**Short:** Can you disable the accessibility feature that zooms on triple tap for your application or view in the manifest file or in the code? Other option would be to tell the user to disable it himself, but that is not user friendly.

**Long:** Android has a triple-tap to zoom feature in accessibility settings. In a tapping intensive game, this makes the screen zoom in and out the whole time. Another problem with this is that it introduces a delay on the tap. Because: you tap, but the OS can't know yet if you are willing to do a simple single tap, or are about to tap two other times in order to zoom. So, it waits a bit to make sure that you are not willing to zoom. This delay makes games unplayable.

Comment: No, you can't disable it from an app (as of Android L). You might consider posting a feature request to the [AOSP issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/list).

Comment: @alanv Please consider giving this comment as an answer.