# Programmatically how to Turn Off Triple Tap to Zoom on Android Activity

Tags: android, gesturedetector

I need to disable zoom, when triple tap on activity.

The Magnification Gestures can be turn off in System settings-> Accessibility. But this will turn off for all apps. I need to do this for activity in my app, programmatic ally.  I found GestureDetector.OnDoubleTapListener interface, but nothing for triple tap. Please, somebody give some idea.

Comment: I was investigating on this, I found more info regarding this issue at, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27554857/android-disable-triple-zoom-for-one-application. it is suggested, as of Android L, it is not possible to disable triple tap zoom for an application. Please share if any more updates.

Answer (score 0):

Old thread but I was able to find a workaround...

While I couldn't find a way to disable triple tap programmatically, [how to detect accessibility settings on android is enabled/disabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37422895/how-to-detect-accessibility-settings-on-android-is-enabled-disabled) showed a way to detect if that setting is enabled. With that, you can give the user a message or instructions how to disable. Especially useful since Samsung Galaxy S8 seems to come with triple tap zoom pre enabled.