# Can the accessibility "Magnification Gesture" be detected on Android?

Tags: java, c#, android, unity-game-engine, accessibility

I've got a game app and it requires repeated tapping. Some players are complaining that it doesn't work when they have the "triple tap to zoom" accessibility gesture enabled on their device.

Web search showed me that it [can't be disabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27554857/android-disable-triple-zoom-for-one-application) within my game, but can it be detected? At least then I can explain to users how to turn it off while playing.

I'm not sure which android API I could use to check this setting. I'm not a native android developer, I work in Unity and Google isn't turning up anything.

Comment: Probably this SO post https://stackoverflow.com/a/37444704/2710486

Comment: Thanks this is somewhat useful. I found AccessibilityService.MagnificationController, but that only seems to tell you when a zoom has happened, not specifically the cause (triple tap to magnify). I'm interested in the system setting to know if that specific magnification gesture is enabled and/or used.

Comment: I thought `ACCESSIBILITY_DISPLAY_MAGNIFICATION_ENABLED` could tell you, however it's a private API.

Comment: This worked!  I was able to add a check using this. I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [zcui93](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2710486/zcui93), I was able to test for this setting using the following Java:

```
Settings.Secure.getInt( context.getContentResolver(), "accessibility_display_magnification_enabled" );
```

...just check the return value: 1 = enabled, 0 = disabled

Here's the code to do it in a Unity C# Script:

```
public static bool CheckForSystemZoomEnabled()
{
    #if UNITY_ANDROID
    try {
        using(AndroidJavaClass clsUnity = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer"))
        {
            AndroidJavaObject objActivity = clsUnity.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");
            AndroidJavaObject objResolver = objActivity.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("getContentResolver");
            using(AndroidJavaClass clsSecure = new AndroidJavaClass("android.provider.Settings$Secure"))
            {
                int val = clsSecure.CallStatic<int>("getInt", objResolver, "accessibility_display_magnification_enabled");
                return val != 0;
            }
        }
    } catch(System.Exception) { }
    #endif
    return false;
}
```