# Android Magnification Gesture

Tags: android, magnification

Is there a way to programatically (or through the Android Manifest file) disable Magnification gestures (triple tap for zoom)? My UI code is written in javascript/html/css, and I saw the behavior on a Pixel C.

Comment: According to the following question ["Android: Disable triple zoom for one application"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27554857/android-disable-triple-zoom-for-one-application) it is not possible.